# File.exists with a .avi extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this function

```
private void setLink(TableCell tc, string sFileName)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("../Documents/" + m_cbCategory.SelectedItem + "/" + sFileName);
    string[] sSupportedExt = { ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".avi" };

    foreach (string sExt in sSupportedExt)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath + sExt);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.ID = sFileName + sExt;
            link.Click += new EventHandler(DownloadItems);
            link.Text = "";
            var img = new Image();
            img.Attributes.Add("src", "../images/" + sExt.Substring(1) + ".png");
            img.Attributes.Add("alt", "");
            link.Controls.Add(img);
            tc.Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to read files like pdf, doc or avi. This function work fine for pdf and doc documents, but what about avi videos? Is there a reason that file.exists returns false for that file and true for the others? I looked about the file spelling, path and everything is good...

Comment: I'm afraid that make no sense. Have you tried with different AVI files?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work if filename, ext and path are all equal. There are no special exceptions.

Comment: Are the videos in the "Documents" folder? Also, beware that "../Documents" is a relative path.

Comment: What about static method `File.Exists(path)` - what does it return?

Comment: Thanks Claudio Redi, you got it. I tried an other .avi (900kb), renamed it like the old one (49000kb) and it worked. Looks like my first .avi file has something wrong. Can it goes wrong if the .avi file is too big?

Comment: Videos were in a folder manually created called documents. That was not the default documents folder :)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have whitespace in the sFileName

Comment: Yes there is whitespace, but that's not the problem. Tried anoher avi file with same name and it worked. Looks like my first avi file has a problem.